# data from React UseContext is undefined for a period

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

```js
const [districtData] = useContext(DistrictDataContext);
    console.log(districtData); //undefined then available
    return (
        <Row>
            <Col md={{ span: 6, offset: 3 }} style={{ height: "50vh" }}>
                {" "}
                <GoogleMapReact
                    bootstrapURLKeys={{
                        key: "#",
                    }}
                    defaultCenter={{ lat:#, lng: #}}
                    defaultZoom={10}>
                    {districtData.map(function (item) {//undefined})}
                </GoogleMapReact>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    );
```

My react context data remains undefined for awhile when i try to console.log it. But it logs after short second but by that time my `map higher order function` has failed. I am not sure how to deal with this. I was thinking of using `useEffect` but the useEffect is already **applied** in the `context provider` to run on component did mount.
I tried to remedy it by checking if the `districtData` is available at first like this:

```
{districtData && districtData.map(function (item) {
return <MarkerComponent details={item} />;
})}
```

This gives `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions` which is weird because Why is it expecting an assignment? **Edit** this was because i didn't return in map function. But the data is still unpresent.
Why is the console.log undefined at first. Will that ever cause a problem?

Comment: Where are you setting the context?  Note: the parent isn't mounted until all children are mounted, so might be a life-cycle issue.  So you might need to return until districtData is not undefined - if you have a dependency on it

Comment: I set my context in the ```App``` component like so ```function App() {
 return (
  <Container fluid>
   <DistrictDataProvider>
    <Map />
   </DistrictDataProvider>
  </Container>
 );
}```

Comment: use lodash function to check if data is present or defined, try this ```{_.isNull(districtData) && districtData.length && districtData.map(function (item) {
return <MarkerComponent details={item} />;
})}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{districtData && districtData.map(function (item) {
return <MarkerComponent details={item} />;
})}
```

Will try to render `false` in the case `districtData` is undefined, null etc. Could be replaced with an empty array.

```
{(districtData || []).map(function (item) {
return <MarkerComponent details={item} />;
})}
```

`Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions` will go away with parenthesis:

```
{(districtData || []).map(function (item) {
return (<MarkerComponent details={item} />);
})}
```